# Can an Abstract Class in PHP Have a Default Method?

Tags: php, oop

I've most certainly got something very basic wrong here.

Here is the code that is part of my Abstract Class:

```
private $outarray = null;

public function add_to_array($ahref, $docname, $description) {
  $row = array('ahref' => $ahref, 'docname' => $docname, 'description' => $description);
  if (!isset($this->outarray)) {
    $this->outarray = array();
  }
  array_push($this->outArray, $row);
}
```

[image: screenshot]

When I step through the code, though, the **outArray** remains null. It is never created and never populated.

I'm still green with PHP, but this help doc seems to leave me believing that this is OK to do:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

...particularly where they are declaring the *Common method* **printOut()** that performs some action.

I've got 5 elements I am trying to populate `outArray` with, but each of the 5 times I circle into this function, I come out with **outArray** being NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are case sensitive. You have in one place $this->outarray and in array_push you have $this->outArray

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I wished PHP would fail to compile with simple errors like that the way C++ does.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.

PHP is case sensitive, but it does not complain about it because it was assuming I had another variable declared on the fly.

Correct way:

```
    public function add_to_array($ahref, $docname, $description) {
        $row = array('ahref' => $ahref, 'docname' => $docname, 'description' => $description);
        if (!isset($this->outarray)) {
            $this->outarray = array();
        }
        array_push($this->outarray, $row);
    }
```

Comment: Please put your error reporting to include E_NOTICE (if you don't have errors all throughout your code). E_NOTICE **will** kick up a fuss about these things...

Comment: You should also consider using a better IDE. There are some that warn you when accessing variables whose origin cannot be deduced by static typing. (E.g. PHPStorm)

Comment: @Scopey - for large projects, is there a good central location to put this `E_NOTICE` variable (like in the php.ini file)? This is new to me.

Comment: Yes. php.ini has an `error_reporting` directive. `.htaccess` can also do it with `php_value error_reporting -1`. Check [this php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) entry for reference...